# Get ID from while looping

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, while-loop

I want to make an employee leave application, where when an employee submits leave request, his boss will immediately get a notification in the email

My table in database like this

```
id |    name     |      email           | person_in_charge |
1      Michael        michael.com                2
2      Johan          johan.com                  4
3      Lorem          lorem.com                  2
4      Ipsum          ipsum.com                  5
5      Dolor          dolor.com
```

I want to, when user id 1 sends an email, then the one who gets the email is user id 2, 4 and 5, because user id 2 is the boss of user id 1, and user id 4 is the boss of user id 2, and user id 5 is boss all of them.

I've doing using while looping, but the result is the one who gets the email is user id 4 and 5, user id 2 not get the email

Here's the code

```
$currentuserid = '1';

    $show= Users::where('id',$currentuserid)->first();

    if($show->pic_for!=null)
    {
        $pic_for = $tampil->pic_for;

        while($pic_for!=null)
        {
            $query = Users::where('id',$pic_for)->first();

            if($query->pic_for==null)
            {
                break;
            }else
            {
                $pic[]=$query->pic_for;
                $pic_for = $query->pic_for;

            }

        }
        dd($pic);
```

Do you know where I missed ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply do not save the first reference, when you enter the loop. The first `$pic_for` is never added to the array `$pic`.

EDIT/BTW: This code can basically DDoS your own database with that loop. Just an idea, but instead of looping through single instances, you could create a HABTM relation between them. So you could query like `$user->usersInCharge()` and iterate over this collection.

Comment: Hi @everyman, thanks for your answer before, but I still don't understand in your edit/btw comment. Can you explain more ? Thank you